# How to change the ViewControllers frame position inside the PageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

The Code I Have written for loading view controllers in Page View Controllers.
Programatically creating four view controllers and adding them to Page View Controller.
I have changed the view controllers frame position but still not changing in the app

```
    let controller: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    print(controller.view.frame)
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height - 20)


    print(controller.view.frame)

    controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


    let controller2: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    controller2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let controller3: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    controller3.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let controller4: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    controller4.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    let p1 = controller
    let p2 = controller2
     let p3 = controller3
    let p4 = controller4

    myViewControllers = [p1,p2,p3,p4]


    for index in 0 ..< myViewControllers.count {
        NSLog("\(myViewControllers[index])")
    }

    let startingViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
    let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]

    self.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: {(done: Bool) in
    })
```

Comment: in here PageView controller takes more complex on your Concept, if only preview purpose are you tried this concept use simple `Scrollview or Gesture Type`, it will resolve your issue

Comment: I need to create like book  transition style APP anna

Comment: So I have Used pageviewcontroller with View Controllers with curl Transaction Style

Comment: It was coming correctly. but can't able change frame of the view controller inside the PageView controller

Comment: inside the pageviewcomntroller you can't change

Comment: what is best way to do ?